# Redirect to a new page from within a Drupal site

Tags: drupal, url, redirect, external

I'm working with a Drupal site, and we want to set up a special URL that redirects to an external site. In other words, if http://www.mysite.com is our Drupal site, we want to have http://www.mysite.com/external redirect to the external site.

I have very little experience with Drupal and have no idea how to set this up. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

If all you want is to redirect the users to the same site, when they follow a link that takes them to http://www.example.com/external, then you can implement [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) using code similar to the following one:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['external'] = array(
    'title' => 'Redirect', 
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_redirect', 
    'access callback' => TRUE, 
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}

function mymodule_redirect() {
  drupal_goto($url, array('external' => TRUE));
}
```

If the URL to which the users are redirected depends from a value passed in the URL, then you can use code similar to the following one:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['external/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Redirect', 
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_redirect',
    'page arguments' => array(1), 
    'access callback' => TRUE, 
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}

function mymodule_redirect($id) {
  // Calculate $url basing on the value of $id.
  drupal_goto($url, array('external' => TRUE));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could install the [Path Redirect](http://drupal.org/project/path_redirect) module which will let you do exactly that, no coding required.

If you're using Drupal 7, you want the [Redirect](http://drupal.org/project/redirect) module.

Comment: +1 upvote [Redirect](http://drupal.org/project/redirect) works for me too on Drupal 7. Note - be sure to clear all caches after install (either via performance section of admin or `drush cc all` ), to avoid a fatal PHP error: https://drupal.org/node/1948676

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect an existing URL, another way via the UI is to use the popular [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module:

e.g: "Reaction Rule" export, redirect homepage to external domain:

```
{ "rules_redirect_homepage" : {
    "LABEL" : "Redirect homepage",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "init" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "site:current-page:url" ], "value" : [ "site:url" ] } }
    ],
    "DO" : [ { "redirect" : { "url" : "http:\/\/example.com" } } ]
  }
}
```

Can be imported at *admin/config/workflow/rules/reaction/import*

Answer (score 0):

you have to download the modules that Clive mentioned 
and you can add a menu link that redirect to external site without any module

1- Go to admin/structure/menu

2- choice the menu that you want to add the url to and click on  {add Link}

3- add the external Path in "path" field like the following "http://yahoo.com"

good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Drupal 8, you can use the class RedirectResponse to do this.

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

The details of how to implement, you can read this post [How to sample redirect page on drupal 8](http://drupal.uwebweb.com/how-sample-redirect-page-drupal-8)